# Subview of custom UICollectionViewCell apparently not redrawn when cell is reused

Tags: ios, uiview, ios9, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewController` whose `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` returns a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`. This cell has a couple of subviews which are also configured as the cell's outlets (e.g. `cell.dot`, a custom `UIView` that draws a colored dot in its `drawRect:`).

What appears to happen is that (at least some of) those subviews are not refreshed when scrolling the collection, i.e. when cells are reused. The problem goes away if I explicitly mark the subview as needing to be redrawn like so:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // ...
    assert(cell.dot.superview == cell.contentView)
    cell.dot.setNeedsDisplay() // apparently required for dot to be redrawn
    return cell
}
```

Is it normal behavior that subviews of reused `UICollectionViewCell`s are not automatically redrawn? Am I missing something else?

Comment: Xcode 9 beta and Swift 3 - the same behaviour, subview's `draw(rect:)` is not called until directly `setNeedsDisplay` is called on that subview.

Comment: For me I had to call `cell.setNeedsLayout()` and `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` in order to force a redraw. `setNeedsDisplay` did not work for me.